# $().next() returning the same element multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I tried to name the title as best I could. A little difficult for me to explain.

I'm having an issue with some code I'm writing (which runs in a widget on my wordpress site.) What I've written here emulates this issue. Just fyi I'm very new to jquery, JS, etc.

What I'm trying to do is set the variable "thumb" to the element after "widget-code". It works, however it's only finding that element ("thumb-class") in "wordpress-post1"

The console output is:

```
wordpress-post1
wordpress-post1
wordpress-post1
```

But it should be:

```
wordpress-post1
wordpress-post2
wordpress-post3
```

This is the actual code

```
<div class="wordpress-post1">
    <div id="widget-code">
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var thumb = $("#widget-code").next();
                console.log(thumb[0].parentElement.className);
             });
        </script>
    </div>
    <div class="thumb-class">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="wordpress-post2">
    <div id="widget-code">
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var thumb = $("#widget-code").next();
                console.log(thumb[0].parentElement.className);
             });
        </script>
    </div>
    <div class="thumb-class">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="wordpress-post3">
    <div id="widget-code">
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var thumb = $("#widget-code").next();
                console.log(thumb[0].parentElement.className);
             });
        </script>
    </div>
    <div class="thumb-class">
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm going to try and clarify a little more:

This code is placed in an html widget which the wordpress theme I'm using provides. It hooks into each post. This is the only place I can put code, and this is the only code I've written. (I haven't altered the theme's files in any way.)

I have no control over the name of the classes or IDs. And they're dynamic. An unlimited number of posts could exist. Therefore I can't hardcode anything.

In order for this code to work correctly it'll need to find the sibling of the "widget-code" element in only the post it's running from.

This is the link to the code on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pattnvy3/

Would appreciate any help on the matter.

Comment: You can't have several elements with the same ID.

Comment: `id` MUST be unique on the page

Comment: invalid markup.......ids should have to be unique per element.

Comment: ID's should be unique.

Comment: and iven if you use class instead of id - it work as it should.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/19q6zvax/1/ - You can use a single js block where you iterate over each `widget-code` element and find its parent

Comment: The ID selector will return the first element with the given ID, so your selector `$("#widget-code")` will always return the first `<div id="widget-code">` which is in `wordpress-post1` that is why the same value is printed 3 times

Comment: That may be so about the ID, however I have no control of it.

@ArunPJohny
I see why it's not working then, thanks for the info. 

Regarding your example, the code that I write must only find the element for the post it belongs to. In other words, I can't have a function that runs for all the posts as in your example.

Comment: @Tsel but you will be able to change the markup of each block isn't it.. like change the id to class.... If the script is present in each block and the block is created dynamically why can't you use the same server side varible to findout the class name in script too

Comment: @Tsel Assume your server script is like `<div class="wordpress-post{{index}}">` then in your script `var thumb='wordpress-post{{index}}';`

Comment: @ArunPJohny

I don't want to edit the theme's PHP files, otherwise my changes will be lost when the theme is updated by the developer.

I can't change the ID. The class. Or anything about it.

I simply have an html widget which is placed in each post. It's going to run as many times as there are posts. So if I have 25 posts, it'll run this code 25 times. So I can't have the code itself loop through all 25 posts, as it'll then be running 625 times each page load.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @Tsel If each `wordpress-post` is created via javascript, I think it would be a good idea to display the function that updates your page and adds the new page elements. Displaying relevant source code is a must, otherwise people can keep submitting answers that will make your  example work but without knowing/seeing the real functionality and issue you're dealing with, those answers will be worthless to you. I have submitted something that will work but the more I read comments on other answers, I think you're forgetting to include where the data is coming from be begin with.

Comment: @NewToJS

I was trying to avoid that. As it's a Wordpress site, there's a lot of related files.

So I tried to write an example which would create the same issue without involving the original code. However it seems I wasn't clear enough on my limitations. I'll try and clarify my original post more.

Comment: @Tsel well by avoiding it, it has caused misleading/misunderstanding of the real issue hence all the changes to the current answers.  If you cannot be clear on what you want to achieve and how it works then people cannot help you. If you have new data being added to the page, using onload/read will not do anything as the function has already executed on page load / when ready. Sometimes its worth the essay of relevant information/description to avoid misleading/misunderstanding.

Comment: @NewToJS

I really believe the actual code would be far too complicated -- since it's not my theme, it involves things I haven't coded or altered. It's simpler if I just tell everyone the constraints I'm working with.

Comment: @Tsel I have given a workaround that fits your question, if it doesn't work then i'm sorry but I don't believe I can help you on this occasion as i'm finding it hard to understand why this wouldn't work for you. I wish you the very best of luck with finding a solution.

Comment: @NewToJS

No worries. Thanks for your help, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a nasty hack, try

```
<div class="wordpress-post1">
    <div id="widget-code">
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var c = window['widget-code-counter'] || 0;
                window['widget-code-counter'] = ++c;
                var className = 'wordpress-post' + c;
                console.log(className);
             });
        </script>
    </div>
    <div class="thumb-class">
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/19q6zvax/)

It will give the container class `wordpress-post1`, then you can use it to find any of the descendant element.

Answer (score 0):

This can help if you want to have multiple IDs:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("[id^=widget-code]").each(function(){
        console.log(this.parentElement.className);
    });
});
```

But, still multiple same Ids are not recommended.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pattnvy3/1/)**

**Update**: Declare a global variable `var i=0;` and keep increment it like :

```
<div class="wordpress-post1">
    <div id="widget-code">
        <script>
            var i=0;
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var thumb = $("[id^=widget-code]").next();
                console.log(thumb[i++].parentElement.className);
             });
        </script>
    </div>
    <div class="thumb-class">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="wordpress-post2">
    <div id="widget-code">
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var thumb = $("[id^=widget-code]").next();
                console.log(thumb[i++].parentElement.className);
             });
        </script>
    </div>
    <div class="thumb-class">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="wordpress-post3">
    <div id="widget-code">
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var thumb = $("[id^=widget-code]").next();
                console.log(thumb[i++].parentElement.className);
             });
        </script>
    </div>
    <div class="thumb-class">
    </div>
</div>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pattnvy3/2/)**

Comment: Unfortunately I can't have a function which iterates over all the elements. Rather, the code has to only find the element in the post it belongs to.

This may not be possible to do.

Comment: It's only one block of code which can be executed in each post. In other words, it has to be all the same. So I wouldn't be able to hardcode it like that.

Comment: @Tsel Well you can do it with declaring a global variable i, and incrementing it with 1 , see the answer .. this should help you .

Comment: Unfortunately I have no where to add a global variable. The only place I can add code is in the html widget.

Answer (score 0):

As per the immediate comments, it is invalid markup to use an id for multiple elements.  That said, changing your id to a class such that:

```
<div class="wordpress-post[some-number-here]">
    <div class="widget-code">
    </div>
    <div class="thumb-class">
    </div>
</div>
```

would allow you to to a jQuery selector like so:

```
$('.widget-code').each(function (){
    var thumb = $(this).next();
    console.log(thumb[0].parentElement.className);
});
```

However, if I may make a recommendation, I would say that you tag each of your wordpress-post divs with the class "wordpress-post" and then have a more specific id which is the value you want to print.

Then it would look like this:

```
<div id="wordpress-post[some-number-here]" class="wordpress-post">
    <div class="widget-code">
    </div>
    <div class="thumb-class">
    </div>
</div>
```

and your javascript like this (with jQuery):

```
$('.widget-code').each(function (){
    var post = $(this).closest('.wordpress-post');
    console.log(post.attr('id'));
});
```

or even simpler:

```
$('.wordpress-post').each(function (){
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

depending on the needs you have.   If you have any questions as to what you need, feel free to comment and I will get back to you as soon as I can.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately the issue I have is that the code needs to only find the element for the post it belongs to. I can't have a function that runs and iterates over all the elements. This code will be called for each post -- and I can't control that. So the code itself has to only find the correct element from the place it's being run from.

Comment: So to clarify, is this something that fires when a button is pressed, or is this something that fires on page load?

Comment: @GKnight I would assume on page load/ready, hence `$(document).ready(function() { });`

Answer (score 0):

A pure javascript method:

This is just a workaround since you have no control over `ids` or `classes`, this will target all div elements on the page, loop through them and search for any that contains `wordpress-post` in the class name.

```js
window.onload=function(){
var posts=document.getElementsByTagName('div');
 for(var i=0; i<posts.length; i++){
   if(posts[i].className.indexOf("wordpress-post")> -1){
     console.log(posts[i].className);
     //Snippet Use 
     alert(posts[i].className);
   }
}}
```

```html
<div class="wordpress-post1">
    <div id="widget-code"></div>
    <div class="thumb-class"></div>
</div>
<div class="wordpress-post2">
    <div id="widget-code"></div>
    <div class="thumb-class"></div>
</div>
<div class="wordpress-post3">
    <div id="widget-code"></div>
    <div class="thumb-class"></div>
</div>
```

If you have any questions, please leave a comment below and I will get back to you as soon as possible.

I hope this helps. Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for your help. However the code can't iterate through all elements as the block of code will be run for each post that exists. So if there's 10 posts, the code will be executed 10 times. So it needs to only find the element for the post it belongs to.

Comment: @Tsel I have updated the answer, I did delete it as I wasn't aware that you have no control over the id/classes but I have come up with this as a workaround.

Comment: Hmm I still think there's the same issue. The JS function you wrote would end up being executed as many times as there are posts. So rather than just finding the element in the post the code is running from, it'll find all of them. So there'll be post count^2 iterations, which I assume is bad.

Comment: @Tsel you haven't said when the function is to be called, we can only go by your example/snippet and your snippet is using onload/read to trigger the function. You haven't shown where the page elements are coming from so as far as i'm aware these elements are on the page from load. If elements are being added after page load then I would recommend you display the function that adds them as this would be relevant to your question and current source code.

Comment: It's hard to explain that because this isn't a wordpress theme I wrote. The theme offers a html widget which I believe hooks into the post loop. Whatever I put in that widget will show up in each post. And the code runs when the document is ready. (I.E., when the entire page is finished loading, including all posts.)

Comment: @Tsel Then place the code within the onload=function() into whatever it is you have in place that detects all posts are loaded, this will console.log all the class names as you asked for.

Comment: I can't. No such place exists. I've not altered any of the theme's files. I'm only able to place code in the html widget.

Comment: Ah so you can only place the js in the widget, I wasn't aware of that. This is why it's important to give as much information and be clear as possible. I thinks **Arun P Johny** answer should work for you.

Comment: Apologies for any run around. I did give it a lot of thought, but obviously I missed some things.

I'm just looking at that right now, and it's looking promising.